# Is it possible to detect that a web service was written in .NET?

Tags: asp.net, .net, web-services, soap, wsdl

I am trying to write a client program for consuming a SOAP web service using ksoap2.

I don't know how to find out if a WSDL is .NET based. In a video tutorial I watched, they said that since the URL contains the term "asmx" ([this one](http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx?WSDL)), which stands for ASP.NET, so it is a .Net based web service.

But if I have any other web service and its WSDL, all I see is an XML schema (and I have seen URL's of WSDL's which do not contain "asmx"), how do I get to know if it is a .NET based webservice or not? Is it generally possible to detect?

Comment: The most important thing: why do you think it should matter? If a web service is good implemented, it shouldn't matter, because they should be portable. Yeah, at least in theory. Extensions in most tools can be changed (a matter of configuration), and URLs can be rewritten (for example, ModRewrite on Apache).

Comment: It matters because while writing an Android client to consume the web service, there is something like: `soapEnvelope.dotNet=true;` or `soapEnvelope.dotNet=!true;`

Comment: it would be interesting to know why they needed to make that flag. Is it some incompatibility on the Android or .NET side. But it means, that there's something problematic in the XML structure and that something can be used as a signature... I would look in that way. As I've written, in theory every SOAP-compatible library should cooperate with every SAOP-compatibile web service, in practices some languages have problems with it, and Java is one of them.

Comment: In my experience the most popular java/wcf interoperability problem is timestamp in security header.

Answer (score 1):

`.svc` extension can be some pointer for WCF service. You can also browse service url (something like http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/combobox/examples/loadondemand/wcf/ComboBoxWcfService.svc), WCF services display information page.

Comment: If someone doesn't make effort to hide the platform, it should be enough to inspect Server and X-Powered-By headers.

Comment: You are right, it is a better solution to look in response headers.